# Any tips on moving support for an open source research project to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

My research lab wants to consider moving support for our project onto Stack Overflow, and I was wondering if anyone had tips to make the transition smoother.

I am considering seeding the tag with a few questions from the past, and then sending an email to our mailing list to encourage people to ask questions that are within scope under our tag instead of to the mailing list.

Is there anything else I should consider?

Comment: Don't?  Few tips: 1) Don't seed. 2) Don't just willy-nilly tell people to use SO;  causes people who use the software to post support questions to SO about it. SO is for developers to ask programming questions 3) Be active in that tag; and its popularity has to be outside of your immediate team. 4) This really only works if you have a very large project that is popular.

Comment: @georgestocker without any seed the tag cannot exist.

Comment: Sounds like that's your answer.  can't force adoption or popularity.

Comment: Tell people to ask their *programming* questions about it here, and monitor it as George said. As long as someone with 1.5K rep uses your library and has a question, the tag will create itself!

Comment: Our project is similar to reddis. It is targeted to developers.  I can't monitor it without a tag.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195562 http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13282

Comment: [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) is the best way to go about it.  You can skip that, never worked out well.

Comment: Why don't you experiment with this first? Next time someone asks a programming question on your mailing list, ask 'em to try asking it on SO - just for fun. See how they do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before considering what should you do, it might be even more important to think about what you should not do.

Should do

- Ask questions about how to use the api?
- Ask questions about unclear errors messages

Should not do

- Stack Overflow is not a place to report bugs or make feature suggestions, those should be handled by the organization
- Everything that is not programing question should not be asked here as well.

I think it will be a good idea to take Stack Overflow [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

And good luck, Stack Overflow welcomes you!